# How to make esper epl divide section and compare value

Tags: real-time, esper, epl

I am new using `esper`. I don't know well about `esper epl`, so I'm in trouble.

Problem is this.

User define the value section.

```
For Example,

Level1 : 1~3
Level2 : 4~6
Level3 : 7~9
```

So when the data come first, check the section and make events.
But previous value and new value is same level do nothing `(ex. prev value=1, next value=2 These are in same Level1)`.

In other words, when data is come, check the previous value and level.
If they have different level, do something.

Esper Epl can do this? How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "prior" and the "prev" both give you access to the event before a given event. The SQL standard "case when then" is the if-then-else of SQL standard.
You could do something like this:

```
insert into CategorizedStream select 
 case when value between 1 and 3 then 1 
   when value between 4 and 6 then 2
   when value > 6 then 3
 end as level from SomeEvent;

select * from CategorizedStream(prior(level) != level);
```

One could probably use prior and case-when to do this in one EPL statement but I think it becomes more readable by using two statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I developed rule your answer's way!